# Offline Data Augmentation in Google Colab - Problems with RAM

Tags: deep-learning, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-datasets, data-augmentation

What would be most efficient way to perform OFFLINE data augmentation in Google Colab?

Since I am not from US I cannot purchase Google Chrome for bigger **RAM**, so I am trying to be "*smart*" about it. For example, when I finish loading 11000 images, first as NumPy arrays and then creating pandas `DataFrame` from them, it occupies around **7.5GB** of **RAM**. Problem is, I tried to `del` every object (`NumPy` array, `tf.data` object etc) in order to check if **RAM** changes, and **RAM** does not changed.

Is it better to try and be smart about **RAM** or maybe write to disk any time I augment image and do not keep anything in **RAM**? If this is the case, is using `TFRecords` a smart approach for this?

Comment: What do you mean to say by "perform **offline**"?

Comment: I mean to make my dataset bigger and then use it for training. For example, I would like to randomly crop each of the 11k images 5x times, that would make my dataset have 55000 images.

Comment: I think a better way will be to use keras data-generator or a custom generator with tf.data.